# vb.net Passing string between Classes

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, visual-studio-2019

I am completly stuck in relativelly simple task when handling serial comunnication. Something which is without any problems in VB6, but I cannot find the solution for VB.net

What I want to do:

1/ Create application with multiple forms which controls instrument.

2/ Intrument can send message anytime. I need to catch such messages and pass them to given form.

There is not any problem to if I have single form application and all the code is inside one class (form).

My idea was to create module or class which handles all the serial communication events (serialcom) and use sub or functions from this module or class  in all forms. It seems to be partially working, but not completelly. My current problem is that I am able to call Subs SerialRead, but I am not able to pass resulting string anywhere but MSGBox. I mean - I can catch incoming string, I am able to show it in MsgBox by I am not able to pass it into the TextBox. I checked hundrets of threads and I did not find the working solution.

My two classes are below.

**Main window:**

```
Imports System.Threading
   Public Class hlavni
        Public sp As New serialcom
        Private Sub InitBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InitBt.Click
            sp.SP_Open("COM1", 57600)
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub ExitBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitBt.Click
            sp.SP_Close()
            Me.Close() 
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub PowerBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PowerBt.Click
            sp.SP_Write("P" & vbCr)
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub EEpromReadBt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EEpromReadBt.Click
            sp.SP_Write("E" & vbCr)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

**Serial communication class:**

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

    Public Class serialcom
        WithEvents SP As New SerialPort
        Public WithEvents zprava As String
    
        Public Sub SP_Open(ByVal P As String, ByVal B As Integer)
            SP.PortName = P
            SP.BaudRate = B
            SP.Open()
        End Sub
    
        Public Sub SP_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP.DataReceived
            ReceivedText(SP.ReadExisting())
        End Sub
    
        Public Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
            hlavni.outputRTB.Text &= [text] 'append text
            MsgBox(text)
        End Sub
    
        Public Sub SP_Close()
            SP.Close()
        End Sub
    
        Public Function SP_Read()
            Dim zprava As String = SP.ReadExisting
            zprava = SP.ReadExisting
            Return zprava
        End Function
    
        Public Function SP_Write(ByVal Str As String)
            SP.WriteLine(Str)
            Return Str
        End Function
    
    
    End Class
```

Any ideas or showing directions are appreciated.
Thanks
Jan

Comment: Have you seen the documentation at [How to: Raise and Consume Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)? It includes an example of how to raise and consume an event that provides data.

Comment: Thanks for response. It looks like good direction. I will check it out and try to implement it to my code.